# Is it safe to automatically parse text as markdown?

Tags: email, server, code-execution

I have a server, which receives text mails from students and I plan to automatically collect their message bodys and parse them as markdown so that I can generate a nicely formatted output as pdf. Is there anything I need to be cautious of if I automatically do this parsing? Is there anything I need to intercept to avoid unwanted behaviour/code execution (similar to a sql injection)? Or is it safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how the parsing and conversion software works.  Although markdown is mostly text, one can insert html code into markdown.  By markdown standards, a markdown parser usually can support the rendering html code.  Basically, if the e-mail has html code in plain text, the markdown converter may copy that text into markdown directly (with no formatting if the text is not formatted).  This may cause html to be parsed from the markdown file.   [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54916136/how-do-you-embed-an-iframe-into-markdown)

I am not sure if you will be using two different or just a single software to convert from text e-mail to md(markdown) to pdf.  However, I do not think that may make a difference.  The only vulnerability I can think of is at your end, where the md to pdf converter may parse the md when converting (which may have html content).  If the converter does not do parsing but just looks at the md file, then there may not be any issue, as there is no way to have dynamic HTML rendered inside a PDF file.

The only vulnerability I can think of relating to html inside of md, is where the html code has an `<iframe src="virus url"></iframe>`.  This may cause your md to pdf converter to download a virus on to your computer.

This is one of the reason why some html elements don't get parsed and are removed from GitHub README.md markdown files.  [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48402823/embed-openstreetmap-iframe-in-github-markdown)